# If the certification of a problem is P-complete, is the problem NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Let's say I have some problem $A \in \mathcal{NP}$, and the problem of certifying a solution of $A$ is a $\mathcal{P}$-complete problem (I'm considering $\leq_{logspace}$ reductions). Does this imply that $A$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete?

**Example / Motivation:** $\text{Circuit-SAT} \in \mathcal{NP}$, and certifying a solution of $\text{Circuit-SAT}$ is equivalent to solving the $\text{Circuit-Value}$ problem, which is $\mathcal{P}$-complete. $\text{Circuit-SAT}$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete.

Does this hold for all $A \in \mathcal{NP}$?

Comment: If you consider $A$ to be exactly $\text{Circuit-Value}$, doesn't $A$ verify exactly your conditions while being in $\mathsf{P}$?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ah that's right, $\text{Circuit-Value} \in NP$ and, being in $P$, it is its own $P$-complete certificate. So I can conclude that does not hold for all $A \in NP$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While the $\mathrm{NP}$-problems we typically study tend come with a natural notion of what a certificate is, for questions like this we need to be careful. Let's recall the certificate-based definition of $\mathrm{NP}$:

A language $L$ is $\mathrm{NP}$, if there is a polynomial-time decidable language $R$ and a constant $k$ such that $$w \in L \Leftrightarrow \exists z \in  \Sigma^{|w|^k} \ \langle w,z\rangle \in R$$

Here, $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes a suitable pairing function. The question now asks whether $\mathrm{P}$-completeness of $R$ (under logspace reductions) lets us conclude something about $L$. However, while $R$ determines $L$, the converse is not true. We can in fact take any given polytime decidable language $R$ and modify it in a way that makes it $\mathrm{P}$-complete without altering what language $L$ it is a certificate language for. We just make $R$ more complicated (if need be) on some useless parts; or eg require a new certificate to be an old certificate together with a solution to our favourite $\mathrm{P}$-complete problem on an instance indexed in a suitable way by the original input $w$.